# Databinding in xamarin for an item in the list

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Is there a more efficient way to toggle the value of checkboxes without having to reassign the checklistsections? As you can see in the code, there are two checkboxes: one is true, and the other is false. When the user clicks on the true checkbox, the false one should automatically uncheck and vice versa. However, my current implementation involves reassigning the checklistsections, causing the entire view to be rendered again, which I believe is not an optimal approach.

Please suggest a better way to handle this scenario to improve the code's performance and efficiency.

Is there any other widget that I can use?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.Converters"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.Core.Models;assembly=xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.Core"
             x:Class="xxx.xxx.ExternalDisplay.App.Views.Checklist"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ChecklistViewModel"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="Black">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        <converters:CheckedColorConverter x:Key="CheckedColorConverter" />
        <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label Text="Checklist Items" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistSections}" HasUnevenRows="True"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistSection">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <!-- Add padding to the StackLayout to create free space on all sides -->
                            <Label Text="{Binding ChecklistCategory.Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5,0,0,0" FontSize="Header" TextColor="White" />

                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistItems}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChecklistItem">
                                        <StackLayout Padding="15" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Purple">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemText}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" >
                                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" Color="Green" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"
                                                              CheckedChanged="GreenCheckBox_CheckedChanged"   />
                                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" Color="Red" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="80" MinimumHeightRequest="50"
                                                              CheckedChanged="RedCheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
                                                    <BoxView Color="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource CheckedColorConverter}}" 
                                                             HeightRequest="20" 
                                                             WidthRequest="20" 
                                                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                             Margin="5,0,0,0">

                                                        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BoxView_Tapped" />
                                                        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>

                                                    </BoxView>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Editor  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryAccentColor}" BorderRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,20" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is how I update the Checklist sections:

```
var a = ChecklistSections;

    foreach (var section in a)
    {
        var itemToUpdate = section.ChecklistItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == checklistItem.Id);
        if (itemToUpdate != null)
        {
            itemToUpdate.Value = value;

            // next two lines just for testing databinding
            ButtonText = itemToUpdate.ItemText;
            a[0].ChecklistCategory.Name = "hi hi hi";
            break; // Exit the loop after updating the item
        }
    }

    ChecklistSections = a;
```

Comment: you shouldn't need to reassign `ChecklistSections`.  It's not clear where/why that section of code is running.

Comment: because of this line -> itemToUpdate.Value = value; 
I need to update the "Value" to change the checkbox in the view

Comment: is `itemToUpdate` observable (and/or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)?

Comment: @jason yes, but I don't want to this approach. The loop and re-creating the view are expensive. I'm looking for better ways to do this, maybe another widget, another approach

Comment: as I said before, I have no idea why you need this or where/why it is being called.  If you properly use databinding this should not be neccesary

Comment: the reason is being called is that, if the user clicks on the true button, the false button gets unchecked and vice versa. Which part is not clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254780/discussion-between-sina-s-and-jason).

Comment: both checkboxes are bound to `Value`.  If you correctly use `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then the databinding mechanism should handle all of this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason has proposed a good method that can help you achieve the desired function. That is to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

To be more detailed, you may consider my code below.

1.Bind two CheckBox to different values in model:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value1,Mode=TwoWay}" Color="Green" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"
         />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value2,Mode=TwoWay}" Color="Red" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="80" MinimumHeightRequest="50"
```

2.And `ChecklistItem` model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This could help you handle the work. Each time, you change Value1 which for the first checkbox, the Value2 for the second checkbox is also changed.

```
public class ChecklistItem :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
    public bool value1;
    public bool value2;

    public bool Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return value1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value1 != value) 
            {
                value1 = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value1)));
                Value2 = !value;                                   
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return value2;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value2 != value)   
            {
                value2 = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value2)));
                Value1 = !value;                
            }             
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Hope it helps!